# absolutePanel always positions relative to window, not parent object

Tags: html, r, shiny, position

i am trying to lay an absolutePanel over a map, and position it relative to another div that has exactly the same size and behaviour as the map.

However, I can't get it to act like the documentation says here in the first part

> The way absolute positioning works in HTML is that absolute coordinates are specified relative to its nearest parent element whose position is not set to static (which is the default), and if no such parent is found, then relative to the page borders.

```
#### Missions: Activity map ####
    tabPanel(
      "Activity map",
      div(
        position = "relative", # my parent div that I am trying to reference
        div(
          class = "outer",
          tags$style(type = "text/css", "#map {height: calc(100vh - 110px) !important;}"),
          leafletOutput("map")
        ),
        absolutePanel(
          top = 100,
          left = 85,
          width = 320,
          height = "auto",
          fixed = TRUE,
          style = "padding:15px; background:rgba(232, 232, 232, 0.8); bottom:25px",
          div(
            style = "margin-bottom:15px;",
            h6("Activity map"),
            p(
              "This map helps to get an overview of the spatial and temporal dimension of UN peacekeeping activities. It shows where missions were employed in each year and which activities they implemented."
            ),
          ...
          )
```

The parent div indeed resizes with the window exactly as the map. I just need to reference the absolute panel in regard to it.

Many thanks!

Tried so far:
different position tags, fixed = TRUE/FALSE, checked in browser inspecting the Shiny app if the divs are indeed created correctly, they are.

Answer (score 0):

`position` is a CSS property. You have to replace `position = "relative"` with `style = "position: relative;"`.